# Angular material: How to set required validator as optional in reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validator

How to set `required` validator as optional is reactive form. I've two inputs `amount` and `volume`. if user choose `amount` radio button, **required validation** must be removed from `volume` input. If `volume`, required validation must removed from `amount`

**app.html**

```
  <form #recForm="ngForm" name="form" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <div>
        <div class="label">
          <mat-label>Charged by</mat-label>
        </div>
        <mat-radio-group (change)="onChargesType($event)">
          <mat-radio-button
            *ngFor="let charges of chargedBy; let i = index"
            [checked]="i === 0"
            [value]="charges"
            >{{ charges }}</mat-radio-button
          >
        </mat-radio-group>
      </div>

      <mat-form-field *ngIf="!isAmount">
        <input formControlName="volume" matInput placeholder="Volume" />
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field *ngIf="isAmount">
        <input formControlName="amount" matInput placeholder="Amount" />
      </mat-form-field>
  </form>
```

**app.ts**

```
chargedBy: string[] = ['amount', 'volume'];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isChargedByAmount = true;
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      volume: ['', []],
      amount: ['', []],
    });
  }

  onChargesType(event: MatRadioChange) {
    if (event.value === 'amount') {
      this.form.get('amount').setValidators(Validators.required);
      this.form.get('volume').clearValidators();
      this.isChargedByAmount = true;
    }

    if (event.value === 'volume') {
      this.form.get('volume').setValidators(Validators.required);
      this.form.get('amount').clearValidators();
      this.isChargedByAmount = false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is because you must call method `updateValueAndValidity()`
When you add or remove a validator at run time, you must call `updateValueAndValidity()` for the new validation to take effect.

I find this from official angular doc https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#clearValidators

Comment: You answered too fast :D 5 min to wait to mark the answer